# How to retrieve the objects of a group

Tags: objects, groups

How to get all of the objects assigned to a group in Blender Python?

```
for group in bpy.data.groups:
    # How to get all objects in group?
```

Comment: The count, or which ones are a part of said group?

Comment: Did you check the API documentation? - its quite clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each group in blender has an 'objects' property which stores all members of that group as a list.

In the context of your script this would loop through each group in the blend file and print the name of each object in that group:

```
import bpy

for group in bpy.data.groups:
    for object in group.objects:
        print(object.name)
```

Although, if you simply wanted to access the list, no looping is necessary, you can simply use:

```
bpy.data.groups['GroupName'].objects
```

You can then access objects with:
 `...objects[0].name`